# Unable to access WCF service hosted on server from c#.net application

Tags: performance, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have created a WCF service to contact sql database.

I hosted the service on remote server IIS.

Service is run and can be able browse from IIS. IIS Browse returns the service URL like below. .

When I try to access the service from outside the server ie from my local system, It is throwing error.
Instead of domain name, I have tried with the system IP and I can able to access the service via IE ()

When I tried to add the service on my .net application it is throwing error.

Error Message From Add Service Reference:

```
<!--The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading '<!--http://sysname:4567/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
  - The remote name could not be resolved: 'sysname'
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://ipaddress:4567/Service1.svc?wsdl'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://ipaddress:4567/Service1.svc?wsdl'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.-->

Error Message From svcutil.exe:

<!--Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://http//ipaddress:4567/Service1.svc
?wsdl
If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have acce
ss, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified addr
ess.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentat
ion at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.
WS-Metadata Exchange Error
    URI: http://http//ipaddress:4567/Service1.svc?wsdl
    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://http//ipaddres:4567/Service1.svc?wsdl'.
    There was no endpoint listening at http://http//ipaddress:4567/Service1
.svc?wsdl that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect ad
dress or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
    The remote name could not be resolved: 'http'
HTTP GET Error
    URI: http://http//ipaddress:4567/Service1.svc?wsdl
    There was an error downloading 'http://http//ipaddress:4567/Service1.sv
c?wsdl'.
    The remote name could not be resolved: 'http'
If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"-->
```

here is my WebConfig file:

```
<configuration> 
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>    
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>      
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>    
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices></webServices>         
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="portalConnectorService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="portalConnectorService.Service1Behavior">
                <host>
                  <baseAddresses>
                      <add baseAddress="http://184.73.184.213:4567/Service1.svc"></add>
                  </baseAddresses>
              </host>
                <!- - Service Endpoints - ->
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="portalConnectorService.IService1">                   
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="portalConnectorService.Service1Behavior">                   
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>                    
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Could any one help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Looks like you are wsdl contains the remote machine name and not its IP address which your machine is not able to resolve. Consider adding the machine name to your hosts.etc with the IP mapping under system32 or else change the WCF service to use IP address rather than your machine name

Comment: I am very new to WCF service. So could you please help me to check and change your settings.

Comment: Is the above web.config of WCF service or your .NET app where you are trying to add reference?

Comment: the above config is from the service hosted on IIS.

Comment: Thanks dude. You reply helped me to resolve the issue. Now I can able to access my service from .Net application.

Comment: I have added this node(<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />) under <System.ServiceModel> in web.config. Now the xml contains my IP address instead of system name. Thanks again dude:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the host section which specifies a base address.
Actually that's ignored by IIS, but try it anyway.

What is the actual error message you're getting?

Comment: an error occured whtil attempting to find the service at 'ipaddress:port\service1.svc?wsdl' Find below the detail error The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'http://ip-0a247a29:4567/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
  - The remote name could not be resolved: 'ip-0a247a29'

Comment: i have removed the host section from web.config, but still the same issue exist...